# Ext js 4: Clicking at empty space in item selector deselects the selection

Tags: extjs, deselect, itemselector, menuitem-selection

Currently the default behavior for item selector is that whenever I click at any empty space inside the item selector , it deselects the entire selection. But I need to implement a behavior where items get deselected only if they are clicked on again and not on the click at the empty space.
Is there any way that I can implement this ?
Thanks.

Comment: please refer this link for example :http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

Comment: I found the solution in case any one needs : Just call 'beforecontainerclick' event and return false. :)